# MAUI Dependencies not found

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I've been facing an issue with Visual Studio 2022 where dependencies aren't being recognized, even though I've installed .NET MAUI and related tools. I've spent the past week troubleshooting the problem without success. Do you have any ideas or suggestions for resolving this?

[image]

Here's my workload

[image]

Here's my `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CheckEolWorkloads>false</CheckEolWorkloads>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows')) and '$(MSBuildRuntimeType)' == 'Full'">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041</TargetFrameworks>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>TodoApp</RootNamespace>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <EnablePreviewMsixTooling>true</EnablePreviewMsixTooling>

    <!-- Display name -->
    <ApplicationTitle>TodoApp</ApplicationTitle>

    <!-- App Identifier -->
    <ApplicationId>com.companyname.todoapp</ApplicationId>
    <ApplicationId Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-windows'))">39619FED-B5E5-409C-8125-60810F06A832</ApplicationId>

    <!-- Versions -->
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
    <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

    <!-- Required for C# Hot Reload -->
    <UseInterpreter Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">True</UseInterpreter>

    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-ios'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-maccatalyst'">14.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-windows'))">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-windows'))">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

    <!-- Images -->
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

    <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
    <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-windows'))">
    <!-- Required - WinUI does not yet have buildTransitive for everything -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graphics.Win2D" Version="1.0.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Resources\Images\check.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Images\plus.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="sqlite-net-pcl" Version="1.8.116" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLiteNetExtensions.Async" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.core" Version="2.1.0-pre20220207221914" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" Version="2.1.0-pre20220207221914" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl" Version="2.1.0-pre20220207221914" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.sqlite3" Version="2.1.0-pre20220207221914" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <MauiXaml Update="Views\OfficialFormPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Views\OfficialListPage.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-windows'))">
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Thanks

Because of this problem I can't run my code, so I hope the cause of the error can be found

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you upgraded your .NET6 app, It is out of support now that's why your project probably can't compile because your installation does not have .NET6.

You can find the Maui support policy [here!](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/maui)

To migrate you need to check these out:

https://blog.verslu.is/maui/upgrade-dotnet-maui-dotnet-7/
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Upgrading-.NET-MAUI-from-.NET-7-to-.NET-8